# make AS3 for each loop dynamically know depth of iteration

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, foreach

I hope I am clear enough.

My data set is populated I have

```
 comment:CommentVO;
 comment.replies=[comment:CommentVO,comment:CommentVO,comment:CommentVO];

_comments:Array = [comment:CommentVO,comment:CommentVO,comment:CommentVO]
```

I've correctly populated my **_comments** Array and the **replies** array in my CommentVO Obj.

This works

```
   for each (var comment : CommentVO in _comments) {
     trace("TOP COMMENT" + comment.raw_message);

         for each (var comment : CommentVO in comment.replies){ 
           trace("1st DEPTH COMMENT REPLY " + comment.raw_message);

            for each (var comment : CommentVO in comment.replies){  
            trace("2nd DEPTH COMMENT REPLY " + comment.raw_message );

               for each (var comment : CommentVO in comment.replies){   
                 trace("3rd DEPTH COMMENT REPLY " + comment.raw_message);
                }   
                }
          }
     }
```

But I knew that the comment replies depth was 3 levels down.
How can i make that loop check to see if comment.replies array has content and run the loop?
It might look something like this but this is not correct.

```
         var i:int=0;
          for each (var comment : CommentVO in _comments) {
              trace("TOP COMMENT" + comment.raw_message );

                      for each (var comment : CommentVO in comment.replies) {    
                     trace( i + "DEPTH COMMENT REPLY " + comment.raw_message );
                             if(comment.replies.length >1){
                             i++;
                        }
                      }

               }
```

I hope I am clear enough....I've been banging my head with this.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to google recursive functions...I don't think you really need to know the total depth, just whether there is anything to see at the current level.

Comment: Yeah I realized recursive functions is my answer but I'm hopping somebody can turn my loop into a recursive one :).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer for anyone who needs it!!! and trust me you will if your data tree is dynamically generated without you knowing how deep the child to parent relationship will be.

```
   for each (var comment : CommentVO in _comments) {
              trace("TOP COMMENT" + comment.raw_message );

                     listReplies(comment.replies);

                     }
               }    


  private function listReplies(replies:Array):void{
             for each (var comment : CommentVO in replies) {          

                            trace(  " >>>>>> " + comment.raw_message);

                 if (replies.length > 0 ){ 
                                 listReplies( comment.replies); 
                                }

               }

        }
```

Comment: If _comments is an Array, all you need is listReplies(_comments), since listReplies already does the loop. Also, shouldn't that be if comment.replies.length>0 {listReplies(comment.replies)}  ?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, each comment can have 0 to n replies, which are also comments that can have 0 to n replies, and so forth.

So you need a recursive function that is called for each comment, regardless of its depth relative to the original posting, but keeps track of that depth.

It should look something like this:

```
function findReplies ( comment:commentVO, depth:int = 0) : String {
    var output:String = formatComment (comment, depth);

    for each ( var reply : commentVO in comment.replies ) {
        output += findReplies ( reply, depth + 1);
    }

    return output;
}
```

You don't need to use a counter variable; the `for each`loop will only execute if the array has content. You call this method on the top level comment and, if you like, you can trace the entire tree at once instead of having a trace call within the function body - like this:

```
trace ( findReplies (topComment) );
```

Implement `formatComment()` to have the output nicely formatted. For example:

```
function formatComment ( comment:commentVO, depth:int ) : String {
    var output:String = depth > 0 ? "  " : "- ";

    var i:int = -1;
    while (++i < depth) output+= "  ";

    output += "Comment ";
    if ( depth > 0 ) output += "reply ";

    output += "at depth "+depth+":";
    output += comment.raw_message;
    output += "\n";

    return output;
}
```

will return:

```
- Comment at depth 0:  {text}
    Comment reply at depth 1: {text}
      Comment reply at depth 2: {text}
    Comment reply at depth 1: {text}
    Comment reply at depth 1: {text}
    Comment reply at depth 1: {text}
      Comment reply at depth 2: {text}
        Comment reply at depth 3: {text}
        Comment reply at depth 3: {text}
```

Comment: Yes that would have worked but got to my version first... But thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test example you may refer to for turning your code recursive:

```
var childStructure:Array = [2,3,1,0];

function test(depth) {

    for(var i = 0; i < childStructure[depth]; i++) {

        test(depth+1);      
    }

    trace("DEPTH " + (depth + 1) + " COMMENT REPLY " ); 
}

test(0);
```

The above will produce an output in console, similar to :

```
DEPTH 4 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 3 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 4 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 3 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 4 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 3 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 2 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 4 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 3 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 4 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 3 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 4 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 3 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 2 COMMENT REPLY 
DEPTH 1 COMMENT REPLY
```